# Embedding Variable in Command Line into VBA

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to embed the below command line into VBA:

```
for /f "skip=10 delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c *.log ^2^>nul') do if exist "%%~fA" del "%%~fA
```

What I tried was:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmdLine = "cmd /k for /f ""skip=2 delims="" %%A in ('dir /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c *.xls ^2^>nul') do if exist ""%%~fA"" del ""%%~fA"""
retVal = objShell.Run(cmdLine, 1, True)
```

It didn't work.

However, if I saved the code as `.cmd`, it worked.

Comment: Define "didn't work"? looks fine here.

Comment: Try using the Chr() function. Single quote is Chr(39).

Comment: Did you want there to be another quote at the end of `"%%~fA`?, your top example doesn't how it, but your bottom example does `""%%~fA""`

Comment: @Mat'sMug, the command didn't delete the files I intended to; also the retVal returns 1.

Comment: So the problem isn't with the single quote at all is it?

Comment: @JasonBrady for the other quotes, the syntax is correct. You can use `Debug.Print cmdLine` to check whether the string returned match your expectations.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have put the original command line into a batch file and ran it successfully. So I suspect it's the single quotes in VBA causing issues.

Comment: Maybe related to whatever the "current directory" is when running VBA vs directly?

Comment: @TimWilliams Forget to mention, I do have `ChDir ThisWorkbook.path & "\Archive"` at the beginning.

Comment: Can you verify that with `CurDir` ? `ChDir` doesn't always work, for example if the previous current directory is on a different drive and you haven't called `ChDrive` first...

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the advice, I tried `CurDir` and it is the correct directory. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Sorry out of ideas  - command line not really my thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue. It's not about the single quote.

You just need to change `%%A` into `%A`. However, if you save the code in `.bat`/`.cmd`, `%%A` works.

It is very finicky dealing with command line.